# json character encoding problem

Tags: json, character-encoding

When I encode an array to JSON I get "u00e1" instead of á.

How could I solve the character encoding?

Thanks

Comment: How do you encode your array and how do you process that encoded array?

Comment: You might want to add which language (PHP/Python/ASP/...) you're using and where your input is coming from (database/HTTP-submitted form/...)

Answer (score 4):

Your input data is not Unicode. 0xE1 is legacy latin1/ISO-8859-*/Windows-1252 for á. \u00e1 is the JSON/JavaScript to encode that. JSON *must* use a Unicode encoding.

Solve it by either fixing your input or converting it using something like iconv.

Answer (score 1):

The browser's default encoding is probably Unicode UTF-8. Try
`<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">`.

Answer (score 0):

One problem can be if you check the response only (the response is only a text but the JSON must be an object).

You have to parse the response text to be a javascript object first (`JSON.parse` in javascript) and after that the characters will become the same as on the server side.

Example:
On the server in the php code:

```
$myString = "árvízrtűrő tükörfúrógép";
echo json_encode($myString); //this sends the encoded string via a protocol that maybe    can handle only ascii characters, so the result on the client side is:
```

On the client side

```
alert(response); //check the text sent by the php
```

output: "\u00e1rv\u00edzrt\u0171r\u0151 t\u00fck\u00f6rf\u00far\u00f3g\u00e9p"

Make a js object from the respopnse

```
parsedResponse = JSON.parse(response);
alert(parsedResponse);
```

output: "árvízrtűrő tükörfúrógép"